# Como recorrer un array dentro de un objeto

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs

Dentro de un objeto tengo unas imagenes que son logos, lo que no se es como los puedo recorrer ya intente varias formas hasta un map dentro de {info.logos} para que al pasarle las imagenes esta las tome y las muestre en la pagina

```
const Portafolio = () => {
  const [infoCard] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      titulo: "hola",
      imagen: ImagenTest,
      // ARRAY DE IMAGENES DENTRO DEL OBJETO
      logos: [LogoHTML, LogoCSS],
    },
  ]);

  return (
    <Section>
        {infoCard.map((info) => (
          <CardProject
            key={info.id}
            titulo={info.titulo}
            imagen={info.imagen}
            // IMAGENES QUE INTENTO RECORRER 
            logos={info.logos}
          />
        ))}
    </Section>
  );
};
```

Comment: ¿Ya verificaste que si llegan las imágenes y que sus extensiones son validas? Si pudieras compartir el componente `<CardProject>`, saludos

Answer (score 0):

La estructura del objeto `infoCard` no es la que quieres. Lo que quieres es:

```js
    const [infoCard] = useState([
      {
        id: 1,
        titulo: "hola",
        imagen: ImagenTest,
      },
      {logo: LogoHTML},
      {logo: LogoCSS}
    ]);
```